# create multiple new datatables for each filtre Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have datatable I want to filter through it and create multiple tables with name of each table corresponds to the filter in python

```
Name Cury Sal
Jim   e    3
jack  y    2
lop   e    1
elis  i    5
ope   e    7
```

the goal is to create from this table 3 different tables using Cury column as filter with each table named Cury_(filter)

Comment: What does your data looks like ? What filter do you want to apply ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
import pandas as pd
Name = ["Jim", "jack", "lop", "elis", "ope"]
Cury = ["e", "y", "e", "i", "e"]
Sal = [3, 2, 1, 5, 7]

df = pd.DataFrame(data={"Name" : Name, "Cury": Cury, "Sal": Sal})
uniqueCury = df.Cury.unique()
df_list = [df.loc[df.Cury == el] for el in uniqueCury]
```

As a result you'll get a list of dataframes, splitted as per unique values of "Cury" column:

```
>>> df_list[0]
  Cury Name  Sal
0    e  Jim    3
2    e  lop    1
4    e  ope    7
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it using the `exec()` function :

```
for value in df['Cury'].unique():
    exec("Cury_{0} = df[df.Cury == '{0}']".format(value))
```

---

Output :

```
print(Cury_e)

  Cury Name Sal
0    e  Jim   3
2    e  lop   1
4    e  ope   7
```